# OpenIMAJ Jar Files

Tags: java, openimaj

I am new to openIMAJ and I want to process some pictures using it. There are a lot of tutorial available but they all tell using Maven. Does anyone know from where I can download the jar files of openIMAJ to directly use in my Java project?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenIMAJ is rather complex and contains a lot of modules that you probably don't need to use in your project (i.e. if your making something to do image processing, you probably don't care to much about audio analysis, or content analysis of web-pages). In addition each of the OpenIMAJ modules has dependencies on numerous other projects (which themselves have dependencies, and so on). For these reasons, it isn't really all that practical to provide direct downloads of all the modules and their dependencies as it would take an incredible effort for the user to try and figure out which bits are needed and which bits are not.

The ideal way to specify which bits of OpenIMAJ you need is to use an automatic dependency management system; this does not need to be Maven however - any Maven compatible dependency manager will work (i.e. Ivy, SBT, Grape, etc...). There are examples of the snippets you need to add to your build system configuration for these on the [OpenIMAJ front page](http://openimaj.org) in the box on the right (you might need to scroll down a bit).

If you really do want to manually include the relevant jar files in your existing project, I'd recommend the following approach, which uses Maven to build a customised set of jars based on the exact OpenIMAJ modules you need:

1. Run `mvn -DarchetypeRepository=http://maven.openimaj.org -DarchetypeArtifactId=openimaj-quickstart-archetype -DarchetypeGroupId=org.openimaj -DarchetypeVersion=1.2.1 -DartifactId=oi-deps -DgroupId=oi-deps -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT -DinteractiveMode=false archetype:generate` to create a basic OpenIMAJ project (called `oi-deps` in this case).
2. Go to the `oi-deps` directory: `cd oi-deps`
3. Edit the `pom.xml` file to include only the bits of OpenIMAJ you need by removing any unnecessary `<dependency>` sections.
4. Run `mvn dependency:copy-dependencies`. This will create a `target/dependencies` folder that contains all the jars you need to add to your project.

Comment: hey, can you look into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31553141/how-to-compare-2-images-using-sift-featuers-in-openimaj and give me an answer?

Answer (score 3):

For all the features of OpenIMAJ there are more than 50 Jar file that you need to Download individually. Also if you somehow manage to find all those files manually on internet you may end up mixing some or other version which will make some classes incompatible. Although I would strongly suggest you to try understand what maven is and its capabilities, you can follow the below steps if you dont want to add dependencies using maven or even don't even want to know what it is.

1.) Go to Help Menu -> Open MarketPlace.

2.) Search for maven and download the plugin.

3.) In file menu create new-> new maven project

4.) Select your workspace and click next

5.) In the select an Archetype window look for add archetype and enter the following details

```
GroupID: org.openimaj
ArtifactID: openimaj-quickstart-archetype
version: 1.1
URL: http://maven.openimaj.org/
```

6.) Click next and give details of your own project and click finish

All the jars will be downloaded which you can see in your project structure. You can now stop worrying about maven and start concentrating on openimaj.

Comment: i tried the steps you listed. at step 6 i get an error "could not resolve archetype org.openimaj-quickstart-archetype:1.1 from any of the configured respositories" .

Comment: I faced the same problem when using a network under proxy (From my workplace). Try from proxy free network (Home). There are other ways to do that but gets a little complicated.

Comment: Yes.. proxy causes trouble. Try from home

Answer (score 1):

I also didn't find any 'download all' site. And I think the reason is that there are a lot of dependences in some jar files.

I extracted some jars recently to use in a project without maven but that was quite wiry.
And I was only able to do this using another project with maven.

I think maven is good stuff and easy to use within ie. netbeans. So give it a try.